# Are Arrow syntax and function syntax really the same? (Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki-api

So I have a really interesting thing happening with my code. When using arrow syntax to declare my function I get an error. But no error when I use the old function() syntax.

```
const clean = (blurb) => {
    blurb.find('a').each(()=> { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()) });
}
```

(Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined)

^^^^Error^^^^

Versus

```
const clean = (blurb) => {
    blurb.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()) });
}
```

^^^^No Error^^^^

So clean should just remove all instances of the 'a' tag but this only works when I use the old method? Any idea as to why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions do not have their own `this`, as regular functions do, which is probably the cause of your error.

More information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions